# Show an inequality using scalar product of vectors

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, vectors, inner-products

How can I prove that:

$$0<r^2<(r^2+(wl)^2)((1-w^2lc)^2+(wrc)^2)\tag1$$

$\forall c>0$ and all the other variables are bigger than zero using the scalar product of the vectors $A=(r,wl)$ and $B=(1-w^2lc,wrc)$?

I do not know how to get started on this problem and I do not see how I can use the  scalar product of vectors to prove this inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $r\ne0$, $r^2>0$ is trivial. The other inequality is $(A\cdot B)^2<(A\cdot A)(B\cdot B)$, which is [Cauchy–Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) for non-parallel vectors (otherwise we could only claim $\le$). In particular, check that $r(1-w^2lc)+wl(wrc)=r$. But $A$ could be parallel to $B$, so $<$ is in general incorrect.